# Recover deleted entries

Tags: web-services, sugarcrm

I am using SugarCRM SOAP Web Service.

I can delete an entry from SOAP by setting

> ```
>     'id'=BeanID
>     'deleted'=1
> ```

But I can't set back as

> **'deleted'=0**

I can do from MySQL(phpMyAdmin) but not from SOAP Web Service.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing anything; this is a bug with the call.

Please vote on the below bug to get it fixed faster inside of Sugar

http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html#issue_58986

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please add the bug yourself? You have better knowledge about this than me. Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, found solution just few moments ago. I didn't test it properly but it seems to work for now.. 
'sugar_root'/include/database/DBManager.php

## Change 1

```
    $where .= " AND deleted=0";
```

to

```
    //$where .= " AND deleted=0";
```

## Change 2

```
    return "SELECT * FROM ".$bean->getTableName()." $where AND deleted=0";
```

to

```
   //return "SELECT * FROM ".$bean->getTableName()." $where AND deleted=0";
    return "SELECT * FROM ".$bean->getTableName()." $where";
```

## Change 3

```
    if($fieldDef['name'] == 'deleted' && empty($bean->deleted)) continue;
```

to

```
    //if($fieldDef['name'] == 'deleted' && empty($bean->deleted)) continue;
```

If anybody find any issues after following changes, pls post it here.
Cheers