# How to undelete SugarCRM entries via the API?

Tags: sugarcrm

Lets say one creates archived emails with a given id.*

Now when the archived email gets deleted using the SugarCRM UI, the record is there but there is no way back.

If (a) the record isn't there or (b) the entry is there but deleted, the API answers you *exactly* the same (so you cannot make your app discern *when* to use new_with_id or a normal update).

Updating the record with deleted=0 has no effect and using again new_with_id reasonably causes an error.

How would you undelete entries via the api?

*using the new_with_id SugarCRM feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known SugarCRM bug ([SugarCRM Bug#58986](http://www.sugarcrm.com/support/bugs.html#issue_58986))

Please see: [Recover deleted entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13625845/recover-deleted-entries)

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have to connect directly to the database on this one and set the delete=0 to deleted=1
I don't think you can undelete something with the API, but this shouldn't be much code to run as long as you can connect to the database.

Comment: thx, but the problem is our software has only access via the api. We could create a new item but one cannot know from the api response if an item was never there or deleted.